# How to load Blender scene with textures, light and camera to three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I was able to export single object (box.json) and scene (box2.json) form Blender using io_three.I also managed to load single object (box.json) with textures using JSONLoader() (modelWithTexture.html).

My objective is to load whole scene with all textured objects, lights and camera to three.js.Till now I managed to load scene with objects and lights, but without textures using ObjectLoader() (scene_noTextures.html) and I'm stuck.

All files, to which I'm referring above, plus .blend file, that I'm using in this example you will find here:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1kP1cNoYxYCfkszUUNBeloxaUY1NnlsbURuRi1ENFhwc1ZfVllIMFQ5SkcyRllZTC05TVU&usp=sharing

I found the answer to similar question here:
[Is three.js ObjectLoader capable of loading textures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723121/is-three-js-objectloader-capable-of-loading-textures)

but In github dev branch is vast amount of different files that I have no idea how to use.

Please help me improve my code so I could complete my objective.(it's not actually my code, I just copied and pasted pieces of code from tutorials, basing on what I've learnt so far)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for attention.
I managed to solve this myself:
All I needed to do is change in "scene_noTextuers.html" setClearColorHex() to setClearColor() and switch my old three.min.js file with new, that I got from here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/build