# Textures not showing up in three.js ObjectLoader

Tags: three.js

Having an issue using a JSON model w/ textures exported from Clara.io.

For those familiar with Clara.io, I'm using File -> Export All -> ThreeJS (JSON) to export and including the files in my ThreeJS project using the ObjectLoader example in [the Clara.io docs](https://clara.io/learn/user-guide/data_exchange/threejs_export):

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load("zebra.json",function ( obj ) {
     scene.add( obj );
});
```

The mesh Geometry is loading fine, but with no texture.

Console is throwing error(s): 'Undefined texture null', yet the texture files are referenced in the JSON file.

Using ThreeJS r74.

How can I load the texture in three.js? The .json file references multiple textures.

I've reviewed [#28723121](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723121/is-three-js-objectloader-capable-of-loading-textures) but a solution from that thread is unclear and I'd like to keep in-step w/ r74.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: If you check the network tab in your browser developer tools - do you see a request for the textures? Do they succeed?

Comment: Good question. Textures are loaded in the network tab but are not applied to the Geometry. Also no longer receiving the 'Undefined texture' console error.

Answer (score 0):

Got the example code working with a different model/texture combo not exported from Clara.io.

Not exactly 'the' answer I was looking for but its a solution for now. Doesn't appear to be a ThreeJS issue.